# Gay Romance novel where the protagonist killed himself and returned to the past (but with a twist)

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading this novel 4-3 years ago on [Novel Updates](https://www.novelupdates.com). The main character (who I'll call 'Q'), is rich and he fell in love with this guy who I'll call 'BS', but it was one-sided.

'Q', being a sociopath, faked the death of 'BS' and kidnapped him. 'BS' tried to escape but got real quick. After that 'Q' then cut all four  extremities of his body and 'BS' had to live on a machine with 'Q'.

'BS' didn't eat anything and as he grew his malnourished body started to die slowly. As 'Q' grew older he realized how messed up he was and begged 'BS' not to die and that quote "needed to get revenge". Before 'BS' died he said to 'Q'

> "Dying is the best revenge against you" (I think).

'Q' killed himself and found himself in the past but 'Q' wasn't in his body but 'BS''s body... that must have been from chapter 1-6, I think.

Comment: Why did you choose Q and BS?

Comment: Well, Like I thought at first A and B but that sounded boring